# Anaconda Navigator gets stuck at loading applications in Ubuntu 20.04 even after updating Anaconda Navigator

Tags: command-line, python, error-handling, anaconda, conda

I tried opening Anaconda Navigator as root and it got stuck at "loading applications" and gave this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/karuna63/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/widgets/main_window.py", line 550, in setup
    self.post_setup(conda_data=conda_data)
  File "/home/karuna63/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/widgets/main_window.py", line 587, in post_setup
    self.tab_home.setup(conda_data)
  File "/home/karuna63/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/widgets/tabs/home.py", line 171, in setup
    self.set_applications(applications, packages)
  File "/home/karuna63/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/widgets/tabs/home.py", line 206, in set_applications
    apps = self.api.process_apps(applications, prefix=self.current_prefix)
  File "/home/karuna63/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/anaconda_api.py", line 865, in process_apps
    app = app(config=self.config, process_api=self._process_api)
  File "/home/karuna63/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/external_apps/pycharm.py", line 111, in __init__
    super(PyCharmProApp, self).__init__(
  File "/home/karuna63/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/external_apps/pycharm.py", line 15, in __init__
    super(BasePyCharmApp, self).__init__(
  File "/home/karuna63/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/external_apps/base.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.set_up_app_directory_path()
  File "/home/karuna63/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/external_apps/base.py", line 59, in set_up_app_directory_path
    self.app_directory_path = self._get_linux_installation_directory()
  File "/home/karuna63/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/external_apps/pycharm.py", line 62, in _get_linux_installation_directory
    for dir_name in os.listdir(root):
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt'
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that the `/opt` directory still exists?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. You are good to go after creating the opt directory. From your home directory type:

```
sudo mkdir /opt
```